# How to debug an issue in a proprietary SQL database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sqldb

Our application from a vendor is using `SQL Server 2008 R2` as its database on the backend. Although rarely, but sometimes an issue comes up that we think is related to their database (for example a performance issue etc.). We cannot modify their propriety database but want to detect transactions going into that proprietary(vendor) database and react accordingly. **Question**: How can we achieve the above in their propriety SQL Server database?

**UPDATE**

I probably did not phrase the above question well. So, I'm writing this update. *What I mean is the following*: In a similar scenario for another application that uses `propriety` Oracle database in its backend we use Oracle’s `LogMiner` utility to detect transactions going into that proprietary(vendor) database and react accordingly.

Comment: React?  What are you hoping to happen?  I would talk to the vendor when there is a performance issue to investigate what's happening.  That's what you're paying them for.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You can talk to the vendor and see if they'll give you an admin login/password into the database directly, but they aren't likely to want to for fear that you will break something and then blame them for it. Your best bet is to file a bug report with the vendor and pressure them to fix the underlying problem.

Comment: Yup.  This is why you pay for support from a vendor.

Comment: @RussellFox Russel I probably did not explain my question well. So, I have added an `UPDATE` section now.

Comment: Well, there are 3rd party log readers that might work, but I'm not sure they will with a database that's been locked down by a vendor. SQL and Oracle are different beasts under the covers. You can try Apex: https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx